# OS X HDD not recognized, but SSD recognized

Tags: boot, ssd, macbook

I am trying to sell a used macbook pro mid 2009

I used to have an SSD in place, but wish to keep the SSD, and substitute in an HDD

I put the empty HDD inside the macbook, but upon boot I got a flashing folder with a question mark inside. I was not able to launch recovery.

I had an external SATA-to-USB that I tried hooking up the HDD to macbook, and that allowed me to launch recovery as well as install OS X El Capitan (latest OS compatible with this 2009 macbook)

The weird thing is this, even with El Capitan installed on the HDD

- the macbook will display a flashing folder with question mark on boot when HDD w/ El Capitan installed is connected internally
- the macbook will recognize and load El Capitan when HDD connected via external SATA-to-USB
- the macbook will still load OS X with the original SSD whether it is connected internally or externally
- when the SSD is booted (and the HDD connected as well), disk utility shows that the HDD is "uninitialized"

What can I try next?

Comment: Can you confirm that your HDD is using GPT and not MBR as its partition table?

Comment: I am almost 100% certain I left GUID Partition Table as the selected option during install - I don't remember changing it

Comment: Wasn't able to solve this - replacing the SATA cable inside didn't make a difference - putting the SSD back internally and selling